# Words Containing the Meaning of Addition of Referential Information

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Hi I am trying to find the verb that describes a correspondent meaning as following:

> While reading text on something, add/write in some addtional/referential information to it.

Like,

While reading a book if I want to leave some 3M memos on it with some explanatory figures, which verb will describe it properly?

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Answered at [What are the technical symbols used in the margin of a page called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177235/what-are-the-technical-symbols-used-in-the-margin-of-a-page-called) (mistitled, and the verb 'annotate' is given).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like ***annotate*** the text ??

Cambridge Dictionary:

[annotate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/annotate)